# My vsto file is not recognized by Office 2007

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, office-addins, powerpoint-2007

I have created an add-in VSTO for powerpoint 2007 but my .vsto` file is not recognized (*apparently the right format is .ppam*) but when I build it creates a .vsto file, how can I get a correct file ?

Comment: Are you building a [VBA Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509.aspx) or a [VSTO Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using VSTO, you need to use a [**Visual Studio Setup Project**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) to install the application. Here is a [deployment guide for VSTO 3.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chhopkin/archive/2008/11/13/deploying-a-vsto-3-0-based-visio-add-in-using-windows-installer.aspx) and [one for VSTO 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx) that should be helpful for you.

Also, but default when you build a VSTO solution on your development machine - it installs itself automatically. In order to uninstall it - you have to [clean your solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx#DeploymentDuringDevelopment).